# Shortcuts suddenly stopped working in Chrome browser

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

I don't know why but all shortcuts related to controlling tab in chrome suddenly stopped working and i have no idea why.

[image]

I haven't installed or changed anything. Just doing the same usual work. The only recent thing that I did earlier (which I never did before) was, opening the emoji keyboard using the control+cmd+space shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution.

Apparently, Chrome disables tab shortcuts when it's in fullscreen mode.

I exit the fullscreen and now the shortcuts are working...